# How can I disable Serilog's automatic exception logging feature?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog, serilog-exceptions

I am using SeriLog(with Loki sink), and I also have an `Exception handler lambda`-[like in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.0), which catches all exceptions happened during code execution and logs them with appropriate labels.

But, Serilog itself, automatically catches all unhandled exceptions and logs them before me. As a result, an exception is being logged twice.

How can I disable Serilog's automatic logging?
This is my current Serilog Config:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((logging) =>
                {
                    var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                            .WriteTo.Console()
                            .CreateLogger();
                    logging.AddSerilog(log);
                });
```

Comment: This isn't really "Serilog's automatic exception logging feature"... Have you seen the [instructions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#instructions) that uses `UseSerilog` instead of `AddSerilog`? I think you might be ending up with the built-in Console logger _and_ Serilog's Console logger, which will end up with double logs.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks for taking your time and answering. I looked at that now, and I ended up finding that the reason for my case is that, Exception is being logged by
1)Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware, and 2)My own middleware. 
So, I need to disable ExceptionHandlerMiddleware, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19740). The problem is that, both my own logging middleware and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware logs the same exception.

The solution is to disable `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`. And I've done it by https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions like:

`new LoggerConfiguration().Filter.ByExcluding("SourceContext <> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware'")`

Final code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using Serilog.Sinks.Loki;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .Filter.ByExcluding("SourceContext = 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware'")
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.LokiHttp(new NoAuthCredentials("http://localhost:3100"))
            .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting web host");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the equivalent of this in MVC5?

Comment: "SourceContext = 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware'" will not work in double quotes